# Version Controling: connect a Databricks Notebook and all of its versions/revision history with DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, version-control, version, devops, databricks

Hi Databricks and DevOps gurus,

I want to connect a Databricks Notebook and all of its versions/revision history with DevOps.
I follow the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/azure-devops-services-version-control) and just before the end I get an error in Databricks:[image: Databricks error]

First I thought maybe I am not providing the right link but after I click "Create PR" it leads me to my DevOps environment(so the link is the right one) and it asks me to make a new pull request.
[image: DevOps New pull request]

As you can see my only branch at the moment is master.

I am not new to Databricks, but I am new to DevOps and version controlling, and I don't know any way of proceeding from here. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you see this error `Error while listing Git repo branches: Failed to retrieve repo branch list: com.databricks.webapp.versioning.BadAzureDevOpsCredential:..`. It is because your azure devops services organization and the azure databricks are not in the same Azure AD tenant.

See below extract from [document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/azure-devops-services-version-control#get-started).

> Authentication with Azure DevOps Services is done automatically when you authenticate using Azure Active Directory (Azure AD). The Azure DevOps Services organization **must be** linked to the same Azure AD tenant as Databricks.

See the similar reported issues [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1116000/error-in-databricks-integration-to-azure-devops.html) and [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/49010) for more information.